# Creation date for Outlook tasks and flags

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks, flag

I am drowning under the volume of tasks I have to do, or ideas that I have (I also track ideas as tasks) that are tracked in Outlook. I had the idea of generating some statistics on tasks completed and added per day so I can see if the total number is growing or shrinking.

However, while it is easy to see how many tasks I have completed each day - I simply go to the calendar weekly view in Outlook and count the number of tasks under each day that are shown in strike-out style - I can't see how to find out how many tasks I have created per day. The problem is that the start date gets bumped every time I defer a task to a later date (which I do a lot, because of my huge task backlog). So I can't trust the start date to accurately reflect the task creation date.

How can I find out how many tasks that I added to my task list today, including emails that I flagged today?

Comment: I‘m afraid there is not a build-in way for this. As a workaround, you can assign a category to the tasks which are deferred to remind you that these tasks are deferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Switch to the Tasks view in the left Outlook Folders pane.
2. Select To-Do List or other My Tasks folder as required.
3. Click the View -> View Settings button on the ribbon.
4. Click the "Group By..." button and clear the "Automatically group ..." check in the top of the window.
5. Select the "All Task Fields" in the "Select available fields from" box in the bottom left corner of the window.
6. Select the "Created" in the first "Group items by" group in the upper part of the window.
7. Click OK, OK.

You're done.